# Inserting into database columns

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to insert into a database using JDBC and each thread will be inserting into the database. I need to insert into around 30-35 columns. I wrote a stored procedure that will UPSERT into those columns.

The problem I am facing is, if you look at my run method, I have around 30 columns written over there for insertion. Is there any way I can simplify my run method so that it doesn't looks so messy which is looking right now for me? And I have few more columns as well. So if I keep on adding new columns there, it will be looking so messy at one point in my run method.

Are there any way to make this look cleaner, keeping in mind thread safety issues?

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private Connection dbConnection = null;
    private CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    public Task() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    dbConnection = getDbConnection();
    callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(Constants.UPSERT_SQL);

    callableStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(2, Constants.getaAccount(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(3, Constants.getaAdvertising(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(4, Constants.getaAvgSellingPriceMainCats(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(5, Constants.getaCatAndKeywordRules(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(6, Constants.getaClvBehavior(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(7, Constants.getaClvChurn(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(8, Constants.getaClvInfo(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(9, Constants.getaClvSegmentation(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(10, Constants.getaCsaCategoriesPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(11, Constants.getaCustomerService(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(12, Constants.getaDemographic(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(13, Constants.getaFinancial(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(14, Constants.getaGeolocation(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(15, Constants.getaInterests(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(16, Constants.getaLastContributorsPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(17, Constants.getaLastItemsLost(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(18, Constants.getaLastItemsPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(19, Constants.getaLastProductsPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(20, Constants.getaLastSellersPurchasedFrom(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(21, Constants.getaMainCategories(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(22, Constants.getaMessaging(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(23, Constants.getaPositiveSellers(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(24, Constants.getaPromo(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(25, Constants.getaScores(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(26, Constants.getaSegmentation(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(27, Constants.getaSellers(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(28, Constants.getaSrpBuyerUpiCount(userId));
    }
  }



    private Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

          Class.forName(Constants.DRIVER_NAME);
      dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

      return dbConnection;
    }
```

This is my main thread code from which I am creating threads:

```
//create thread pool with given size 
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

try {
    // queue some tasks
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfTasks * noOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(new Task());
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    while (!service.isTerminated()) {

    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: You can try my suggestion from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12887046/1065197)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following things are observed in your code:

1. `Constants` is the name of class itself.
2. `getXXX` method is static method in class `Constants`

Going by all above analysis I consider the use of Reflection API to call the `getXXX` methods of class `Constants` and storing those methods in an `ArrayList`. And finally calling these methods in a loop. The code look something like this:

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private Connection dbConnection = null;
    private CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    public Task() {

    }
    public ArrayList<Method> getRequiredMethods()
    {
        Class<Constants> consClass = Constants.class;
        Method[] methods = consClass.getDeclaredMethods();
        ArrayList<Method> requiredMethods = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < methods.length ; i++)
        {
            String sName = methods[i].getName();
            if (sName.startsWith("seta"))
            {
                requiredMethods.add(methods[i]);
            }
        }
        return requiredMethods;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try
    {
        dbConnection = getDbConnection();
        callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(Constants.UPSERT_SQL);
        ArrayList<Method> methods = getRequiredMethods();
        callableStatement.setString(1 , String.valueOf(userId));
        for (int i = 0 ; i < methods.length ; i++)
        {
            //callableStatement.setString(i+2,(String)((methods.get(i)).invoke(null,userId)));
            methods.get(i).invoke(null,callableStatement,userId);
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

And change your `getxxx` to `setxxx` method as follows:

```
 public static void setaAccount(final CallableStatement stat, int userId) {
        final String A_ACCOUNT = "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId
                + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":1360185069691}";
        stat.setString(2,A_ACCOUNT);//2 is the column Number.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal. Looks more cleaner now. I tried your suggestion but it is complaining at few lines like `The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object)` and also at `NameComprator` as well it cannot be resolved something and also `The method compare(Method, Method) of type XMPTask must override or implement a supertype method`.

Comment: It was happening because `(methods.get(i)).invoke(null,userid)` returns Object. I have typecast it to `String` now . See the updated Code.

Comment: Yeah that thing I figured it out. But what about other errors I mentioned? I think you forgot to put class name right?

Comment: I fixed that as well. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: It was Typo mistake . forget to write class before MyComparator declaration. It is fixed now

Comment: One thing I wanted to confirm here is- There won't be a thread safety issues here with the way you are doing? As I will be running this program with lot of multiple threads.

Comment: If you are executing it using multiple threads then you should synchronize every `getXXX` methods of `Constants` class

Comment: can you post here those codes also where you creating multiple threads and calling the methods..?

Comment: sure. let me do that as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24225/discussion-between-farhan-jamal-and-vishal-k)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following utility method:

```
public static void setStrings (CallableStatement stmt, Object ... values)
{
    for (int count = values.length, i = 0; i < count; i++)
        stmt.setString (i + 1, String.valueOf (values [i]));
}
```

in your `run()` like this:

```
setStrings (
    callableStatement,
    userId,
    Constants.getaAccount (userId),
    Constants.getaAdvertising (userId),
    ...
    Constants.getaSrpBuyerUpiCount (userId));
```

This is shorter and much more readable for me.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the suggestion. So that means I should pass out all the columns names from setString method right? And also I am not supposed to synchronize setStrings method here?